# Best class to schedule a task

Tags: java, android, task, schedule

I'm planning to make an app that enables the Mobile Data of the android every X hours for Y minutes. I was wondering which class should I use to schedule this task. Thanks

Comment: Use Quartz Scheduler. http://quartz-scheduler.org.

Comment: @Naren - he's coding to Android - Quartz scheduler won't work for him

Answer (score 2):

For tasks for which the user can give you a specific time and date, you can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to have your task executed at that time.

This way, your app does not need to be running the whole time, and will be launched by Android when the time comes.

You can even use the [setRepeating()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) method to set it only once and have it run everytime.